How to enable net_cls in cgroup and test
I am trying to enable net_cls in cgroup and test it on a raspberry pi 4.
$ cat /proc/cgroups
#subsys_name hierarchy num_cgroups enabled
cpuset      0  71  1
cpu         0  71  1
cpuacct     0  71  1
blkio       0  71  1
memory      0  71  0
devices     0  71  1
freezer     0  71  1
net_cls     1   1  1
perf_event  0  71  1
net_prio    0  71  1
pids        0  71  1
sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=fe4d79e2-02 rootfstype=ext4 f>
ip=192.168.0.207
cgroup_enable=cpuset
cgroup_enable=memory
cgroup_memory=1
swapaccount=1
net_cls_enable=cpuset
net_cls_enable=memory
net_cls_memory=1
swapaccount=1
How do I test to see if it's working?
